# Using sklearn and Python for a large application classification/scraping exercise

Tags: python, scrapy, classification, scikit-learn

I am working on a relatively large text-based web classification problem and I am planning on using the multinomial Naive Bayes classifier in sklearn in python and the scrapy framework for the crawling. However, I am a little concerned that sklearn/python might be too slow for a problem that could involve classifications of millions of websites. I have already trained the classifier on several thousand websites from DMOZ. 
The research framework is as follows:

1) The crawler lands on a domain name and scrapes the text from 20 links on the site (of depth no larger than one). (The number of tokenized words here seems to vary between a few thousand to up to 150K for a sample run of the crawler)
2) Run the sklearn multionmial NB classifier with around 50,000 features and record the domain name depending on the result

My question is whether a Python-based classifier would be up to the task for such a large scale application or should I try re-writing the classifier (and maybe the scraper and word tokenizer as well) in a faster environment? If yes what might that environment be?
Or perhaps Python is enough if accompanied with some parallelization of the code?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use the `HashingVectorizer` and one of the linear classification modules that supports the `partial_fit` API for instance `SGDClassifier`, `Perceptron` or `PassiveAggresiveClassifier` to incrementally learn the model without having to vectorize and load all the data in memory upfront and you should not have any issue in learning a classifier on hundreds of millions of documents with hundreds of thousands (hashed) features.

You should however load a small subsample that fits in memory (e.g. 100k documents) and grid search good parameters for the vectorizer using a Pipeline object and the `RandomizedSearchCV` class of the master branch. You can also fine tune the value of the regularization parameter (e.g. C for PassiveAggressiveClassifier or alpha for SGDClassifier) using the same `RandomizedSearchCV`or a larger, pre-vectorized dataset that fits in memory (e.g. a couple of millions of documents).

Also linear models can be averaged (average the `coef_` and `intercept_` of 2 linear models) so that you can partition the dataset, learn linear models independently and then average the models to get the final model.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, if you rely on numpy, scipy, and sklearn, Python will not be a bottleneck as most critical portions of those libraries are implemented as C-extensions.

But, since you're scraping millions of sites, you're going to be bounded by your single machine's capabilities. I would consider using a service like PiCloud [1] or Amazon Web Services (EC2) to distribute your workload across many servers.

An example would be to funnel your scraping through Cloud Queues [2].

[1] http://www.picloud.com

[2] http://blog.picloud.com/2013/04/03/introducing-queues-creating-a-pipeline-in-the-cloud/